# how to pass xml parameter in ms access vba to ms sql stored procedure?

Tags: ms-access

how to pass xml parameter in ms access vba to ms sql stored procedure? I tried to find this on the web but I can't find it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a pass-through query?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968